# spot package with pdflatex

Tags: beamer, color, highlighting

I need to draw an ellipse around a word in a beamer presentation and I stumbled across the promising [Spot package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/spot).

Unfortunately it does not seem to work with pdflatex and I could not find any hint in the manual.

A MWE is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{spot}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  Blub, \spot<3->[fill=red]{Bla}, blob, \spot(first)[fill=red,color=blue]{blib}, \spot*(second){blib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I included some screenshots.

This is how it looks like with latex + dvipdf

[image: Result with latex + dvipdf]

And this is the result with pdflatex

[image: Result with pdflatex]

Edit2: My version of pdftex is "pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)"

Comment: Your example works ok for me.

Comment: Ian Thompson: I added two screenshots. When you say it works for you, do you get twice the same (upper) result?

Comment: I get three slides. All have the blue and yellow spots. The last slide has all three spots. The result with latex+dvips+ps2pdf is the same.

Comment: What version of pdftex are you running?

Comment: Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) on my linux desktop and the same (via MacPorts) on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: I do not understand: We have the same version and I tried it on two  machines now -- the same result...

Comment: What viewer(s) are you using?

Comment: Ah ok, that was the problem! I used evince, for okular, acroread & xpdf all seems to be fine! Thanks for that!

Comment: Great that your problem is solved. I think the question should be closed as "too localized", as there is little chance that it might help other users.